# Multidimensional indexing from tuple/list in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I would like the simplest way to an element of a multidimensional array in Python from a tuple/list of the indexes.

I.e.   `f( M, (a,b,c) ) returns M[a][b][c]`

Is there a straightforward way to get this without coding it myself?

Comment: Can you give some concrete input and output examples

Comment: Is your `M` a list of lists? Did you consider if `numpy.array` would be more suitable for your need?

Comment: @ImperishableNight:   Yes, M is a list of lists (or tuples)

Comment: @ImperishableNight:   What changes if it's a numpy.array ?

Comment: what can be better than what you wrote? `M[a][b][c]`....

Comment: `numpy.array` supports indexing with tuples, so if `M` is an `array`, `index = (a, b, c); print(M[index])` works.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, because you may not know the dimension of the array when your trying to do something general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy arrays for that.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
x = [ [[1,1,1],[1,1,1], [1,1,1]], [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]], [[3,3,3], [3,3,3], [3,3,3]]]
matrix = np.array(x)
print(matrix[0,0,0]) # prints first element in matrix
```

Comment: Wait, that syntax can't be right, right?  Do you mean matrix[(0,0,0)] ?

Comment: Both work. You can also use matrix[(0,0,0)]. Just copy the script and test it on python terminal. Remember to install numpy via pip install numpy